# Trying to make a javascript program to calculate the volume of a sphere

Tags: javascript

```
    // sphere.js #2
// This script calculates the volume of a sphere.

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function performs the calculation and returns false.
function calculate() {
    'use strict';

    // For storing the volume:
    var volume;

    // Task 1: Get a reference to the form element:
    var radius = document.getElementById("radius");

    // Add an "if" statement here to
    // make sure there is a reference
    if (radius) {
        //Task #2: Add an "if" to make sure the value is positive:
        if (radius > 0) {
            // Task #3: Perform the calculation:
            volume = (4/3)*(22/7)*(Pow(radius,3));
            //HINT: the formula for the volume of a sphere is V=(4/3)*(pi)*(radius cubed)

            // Format the volume:
            volume = volume.toFixed(4);

            // Task #4: Display the volume:
            document.getElementById("volume").id ="volume";
            //Hint: use the same method as in the radius variable assignment call above
        } //End if 
    } end if radius

    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;

} // End of calculate() function.

// Function called when the window has been loaded.
// Function needs to add an event listener to the form.
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

I'm trying to make a script to calculate volume of a sphere. Its a homework assignment so thats why all those comments are there. Its basically telling me what to do.

Well I followed it to the best of my knowledge but I'm still getting an error. The error I get is "SyntaxError: missing ; before statement" on line 30. Which is telling me to put a ; before "end if". I'm guessing thats not the error. I'm guessing the formula is the error.

Comment: The conditional is "ended" by the closing brace `}`. You should get rid of `end if radius` completely.

Comment: You need to take `.value` of the radius element. Also, what is `Pow`? Is there some reason you are not using `Math.PI`?

Comment: There is no `end if` statement in Javascript.  That should probably be a comment.

Comment: @torazburo I wasnt sure how to do cubic in javascript so I googled it an w3school said to use math.pow function

Comment: Task 4 - why are you setting the `id` property? That property isn't visible to the user. If your element is an input set the `.value`, otherwise set the `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula to calculate the volume of a sphere:

[image]

With that in mind,

```
function volumeOfSphere(radius) {
    return (4/3)*Math.PI*Math.pow(radius,3);
}

console.log('The volume of a sphere with a radius of 5 is: '+volumeOfSphere(5));
```

Also, please do not use `22/7` as an estimation for pi, please use `Math.PI`

On the other hand, the reason why your code isn't working is because `end if` is not javascript code. You should remove it, and re-test your code.

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qm6uaapu/

Comment: This is correct in as far as it goes, but doesn't explain the error mentioned in the question, or fix the other problems in the OP's code associated with getting/setting values from html elements.

Comment: I changed that, but now I think the only issue is the task #4, display the volume. Because when I click calculate I get no console errors but it doesnt display the volume. edit: the answer isnt supposed to display in a console. Its on an html form. I'm supposed to use the DOM to replace the original "volume" id with the updated volume id on the form to display the answer,

Comment: That's probably because you have an error in your code. There is no such thing as `end if` in javascript. Remove it

Comment: I took out the end if. The console shows no errors anymore. But still wont display the answer on the html form.

Comment: @berbe01, that's a different issue entirely. Your original question is related to the JS error you were receiving. If you have another question, close up this one, and post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the end if

Because :
1. It doesn't exist in Javascript.
2. The closing bracket "}" for your if already ends your if statement.